# Transferring data between session and variable in Laravel 5.1 is not working with Firefox

Tags: php, laravel, session, firefox

My project does online reservation. When user enters the site they tries search something for given location and date-time. Before the start of the searching in controller I do clear session after transferred some session data into the variables. Then I flush the session and then put that variables back to the session again. This works fine with chrome but won't work with Firefox & Safari.

Here is the my code:

```
    $token = session('_token');
    session()->flush();
    session()->put('_token', $token);
```

When i look the session token after search operation in controller,  token changes everytime for firefox, but it remains same in chrome.
I don't know why this happens.

Comment: Did you solve this? Got the same problem here...

Comment: Hello, I didn't solve the problem with meaningful steps. There were pictures on the page, some of those were causing the problem. When I had removed them it has been fixed. I still don't know why it happened.